# Switching text editors to get better stuff

Tags: text-editor

I am not sure I am entirely happy with `leafpad` as a text editor on my Lubuntu box.

Question: Could I just purge `leafpad` from the system and install `gedit` instead?

Seems to me that `gedit` won't have any real issues with this being done, but I need to ask the experts on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following will remove `leafpad` along with all its configuration files and then install `gedit`:

```
sudo apt-get purge leafpad && sudo apt-get install gedit
```

You can use any text editor you like, gedit(or any other) won't have any issues regarding that.

Comment: @user154723: As my answer serves the query then please select it as the right answer to your question so that others can be notified that the question has been answered.